# In Windows Phone 8, I keep getting a System.WIndows.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

The error message I get is

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

The call stack traces back to this snippet of code.

> 

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            **InitializeComponent();**
            this.Init();

            // Set the data context of the listbox control to the sample data
            DataContext = App.ViewModel;
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);


        }
```

And errors on the InitializeComponent() line.

```
public void InitializeComponent() {
        if (_contentLoaded) {
            return;
        }
        _contentLoaded = true;
        System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/App;component/MainPage.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));
        this.LayoutRoot = ((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)(this.FindName("LayoutRoot")));
        this.SSIDTextBox = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(this.FindName("SSIDTextBox")));
        this.PasswordTextBox = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(this.FindName("PasswordTextBox")));
        this.Auth_ListPicker = ((Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPicker)(this.FindName("Auth_ListPicker")));
        this.SaveButton = ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(this.FindName("SaveButton")));
        this.GenerateButton = ((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(this.FindName("GenerateButton")));
        this.QRImage = ((System.Windows.Controls.Image)(this.FindName("QRImage")));
        this.Profiles= ((System.Windows.Controls.ListBox)(this.FindName("Profiles")));
    }
}
```

I did not get this exception before I converted the WP 7.1 to WP8.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**:
I added the entire exception message, does it help pinpoint the issue?

> 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{64003C1B-A4FD-41FF-A132-2B6C9FE8EDC9}\Install\WifiQR.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{64003C1B-A4FD-41FF-A132-2B6C9FE8EDC9}\Install\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs{64003C1B-A4FD-41FF-A132-2B6C9FE8EDC9}\Install\microsoft.phone.controls.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

Comment: Is there *no* more information in the exception? What does the message part say? (I seem to remember similar things being a pain to fix, but there was always a bit more information than you've given.)

Comment: It's hard to guess what's wrong. Try to removing parts of your xaml page until it starts working, or try to show us the message in the inner exception.

Comment: I included the entire output. Does this help pinpoint the issue? I also tried removing parts of the xaml page, but the exception is still thrown.

Comment: Found the issue! I used the following steps:
More information regarding the exception can be found by:

Debug->Exceptions
Press Add and type in, "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" and select Common Language Runtime Exceptions
Run again to find the exact cause of exception being thrown.

Comment: @DavyLi, you can answer your own question too, in fact it is encouraged to do so on Stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the issue!
I was able to find more information regarding the exception by:

1. Debug->Exceptions
2. Press Add and type in, "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" and select Common Language Runtime Exceptions
3. Run again and it will pinpoint the exact line number causing the exception.

It turned out to be a simple typo.

Answer (score 11):

Just add the permission in your manifest file.

1. Go to WMAppmanifest.xml
2. Select the "Capabalities" tab
3. Now check "ID_CAP_MAP"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this and found that re-adding the click events fixed it.

It occurred when I copied the xaml from another xaml page.

Answer (score 0):

Strg+Alt+F7 of the Application in VS Express helped after WP8-Update.

Comment: can you add a little more detail to your answer, like what that key combo does. If MS change the key combo in a later release of VS this answer will not help other users.

Comment: The Windows Phone is in a sorry state if they ever want people to take it seriously as a platform for development.