# Volume slider c# windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, sdk, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1, volume

I have some problem with a slider volume in my windows phone app 7.1

this is the XAML

```
<Slider Name="volumeSlider" VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="ChangeMediaVolume" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="0.5" Margin="0,146,0,-27"/>
```

and this the simply function ChangeMediaVolume

```
private void ChangeMediaVolume(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> args)
{
   AudioPlayer.Volume = (double)volumeSlider.Value;
}
```

If I don't have this lines all it's ok...
but when they are in the code the debugger show an error.

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Try looking at the answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14117908/394028), it should help pin point the problem

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what's wrong with it. Try changing the line

```
<Slider Name="volumeSlider" ...
```

to

```
<Slider x:Name="volumeSlider" ...
```