# How to get rid of a XamlParseException?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my `xaml` code. This parses an exception. I cannot find what is wrong there. Can someone point it to me?. This is a windows phone application,

**XAML**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="Citysearch.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="DisplayPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="Display city" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="City recog" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="14,151,10,10" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="119,143,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="309" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,168,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="city" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        </Grid>



    </Grid>

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
            <shell:ApplicationBar>
                <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="Reco1" IconUri="appbar.micph.rest.png" Text="mic" Click="Reco1_Click" />
            </shell:ApplicationBar>
        </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The error that I get is shown below:

> XamlParseException occurred : A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll

It occurs on this line:

```
<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="Reco1" IconUri="appbar.micph.rest.png" 
    Text="mic" Click="Reco1_Click" />
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @SaberAmani ,XamlParseexceptionOcuurred : A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll  .this is what i get.

Comment: @SaberAmani .  at InitializeComponent();.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Doesn't the exception message contain a line number and line position?

Comment: @Clemens this line -->  <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="Reco1" IconUri="appbar.micph.rest.png" Text="mic" Click="Reco1_Click" />

Comment: @SonerGönül That's my English. Can you please edit a proper topic?. I do not know what is most appropriate.

Comment: Ok, now that you know the line that makes trouble, don't you have any idea why?

Comment: @Clemens I really don't see anything wrong there. I don't know much xaml but as I see I do not notice wrong code.

Comment: You must have done some typo mistake, follow the answer to the similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117908/in-windows-phone-8-i-keep-getting-a-system-windows-markup-xamlparseexception

Comment: Got it. Made it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it. 
I did this first:

Debug->Exceptions
Press Add and type in,

```
"System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException"
```

and select Common Language Runtime Exceptions,
then it gave me the exact place of where this happens.
Then I removed

```
Click="Reco1_Click"
```

So now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What we can tell you about your problem will be severely limited from the information that you have provided. The first thing to note is that that error is a very generic error and is raised for a great many different reasons... it generally has nothing to do with the XAML, but instead points to an error in a control defined in XAML.

You say that your error occurs on this line:

```
<shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="Reco1" IconUri="appbar.micph.rest.png" 
    Text="mic" Click="Reco1_Click" />
```

This gives you a few possibilities:

1. You *could* have a problem with your `ApplicationBarIconButton` control.
2. You *could* have a problem with your `IconUri` property value (although you should get a compilation error if this was the case)
3. You *could* have a problem with the code in your `Reco1_Click` handler

In my opinion, it is most likely that you have some code in (or started from) the constructor of your `ApplicationBarIconButton` control that is invalid. These types of problems can be difficult to eradicate, but if you just experiment by commenting out different (relevant) parts of the code and trying to run the application again each time, then you should eventually find the problem.

Comment: I removed the click event. the 3rd suggetion of your answer. it works now.